# Trying to print even popsicles for siblings

Tags: python

Hey so im trying to give an input of popsicles and siblings and give away even popsicles to siblings

so if they are even like 10 popsicles and 5 siblings it prints 'give away' and if its not it prints 'eat them yourself' and im a beginner so i feel like i have done it in an inefficent way is there's any better way to do it

here's the code

```
siblings = int(input('sib:'))

def division(x,y):
   global  op
   global op2
   op = x / y
   op2 = y / x
   return
division(popsicles, siblings)
print(op)

if isinstance(op,int) and isinstance(op2,float):
    print('give away')

elif isinstance(op,float) and isinstance(op2,int):
 print('give away')
elif op % 2 == 0:
  print('give away')
elif popsicles == siblings:
   print('give away')
else:
   print('eat them yourself')
```

Comment: what do you mean if they are even ? that they are divisible ?

Comment: can you give some example with sample input and output.

Comment: "Is there any better way to do it" is not a Stack Overflow issue -- this is not a tutorial or review resource.  If you want to discover better ways, keep working on your class materials.  If you want a code review, then post your question to the Code Review site.  Stack Overflow is generally to fix *specific* programming problems; "any better way" is simply too general.

Comment: Thanks anyway guys the answer below helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the mod operator `%` to work it out. Here's how you can do it:

```py
siblings = int(input('sib:'))

if popsicles % siblings == 0:
   print("give away")
else
   print("eat them yourself")
```

Comment: Thanks so much <3

Comment: @YoussefMohamed Glad that it worked for you :)
Don't forget to mark it as the right answer and upvote it so that others can find it easily!